# Generics needed to extend/implement these interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, interface, pcap

I am trying to design interfaces and classes to parse certain types of packets inside pcap-format file. (I know special libraries exist, but I need to do it myself)

So I have a classifier interface, the method would check whether it is a valid packet.

```
public interface Classifier {
    boolean classify (PcapPacket pcapPacket);
}
```

Method of a parser interface would transform byte array inside `PcapPacket` into some fields. `P` stands for a new parsed packet and `S` for statistics.

```
public interface Parser<P, S> extends Classifier {
    P parsePacket (PcapPacket pcapPacket);
    P parsePacket (PcapPacket pcapPacket, P outPacket);
    S parseReader (PcapReader pcapReader);
}
```

Now I have implemented `AParser` which can parse a certain packet or file.

```
public class AParser implements Parser<APacket, AStats>, Classifier {
```

But now I am having difficulties to implement `BParser` on the top of `AParser` considering that `BPacket extends APacket`.

**`public class BParser extends AParser implements Parser<BPacket, BStats> {`**

In `parsePacket` I want to do something like this:

```
BPacket parsePacket (PcapPacket pcapPacket) {
    APacket apacket = super.parse(pcapPacket);
    BPacket bpacket = new BPacket(apacket);

    //extract val1 and val2 from pcapPacket
    bpacket.set(val1, val2);
    return bpacket;
}
```

Line in bold giving compilation error. At this point I understood something is wrong with my approach. Probably, I need to use generics when I define interfaces.

**How would you help me to redesign this code to make it work and flexible in future?**

Comment: My first thought is to change Parser so that it is defined in terms of two other interfaces, Packet and Stats, rather than in terms of concrete classes. It would then not need to be generic, and APacket and BPacket and AStats and BStats would just need to implement Packet and Stats. But I'm not familiar enough with pcap to know if this is feasible.

Comment: @DavidConrad, but for Packet I cannot think of generalization. They might have completely different fields.

Comment: But do they have different behavior as well? Just because they have different internals doesn't mean they can't implement the same interface (think of ArrayList and LinkedList that both implement List, with completely different implementations), but if they have different behavior then not only can they not implement the same interface, they can't inherit from one another either!

Answer (score 1):

Yea, generics and subclasses do not play together well that way. You've already declared a specialization of your parser (AParser) that binds its generic parameter to a given object (APacket). You cannot then extend from this specialization with a different set of generic parameters. Its like you are trying to do this:

```
public class BParser implements Parser<APacket, AStats>, Parser<BPacket, BStats> {
```

Which will not work because type erasure means you have a bunch of methods that translate to the same signature. A more viable solution would be too push the common functionality for your specialized parsers into an abstract base class that does *not* bind the generic parameters to a particular type. Illustrated with pseudocode:

```
public abstract class BaseParser<P, S> implements Parser<P, S> {
    // common functionality here
}

public class AParser extends BaseParser<APacket, AStats> {
    // functionality specific to AParser
}

public class BParser extends BaseParser<BPacket, BStats> {
    // functionality specific to BParser
}
```

Comment: is it okay to mix interfaces and abstract classes?

Comment: and would it be better solution than generics?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - there is no restriction on how you can mix and match interfaces and abstract classes, as long as the combinations do not lead to violations of the Java specification. And this solution still uses generics, it just uses them in a legal (compilable) way.

Comment: Oh, I meant wildcards. Something like `AParser implements Parser<? extends APacket, AStats>` would make sense?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - you can't use a wildcard generic in a class declaration like that. The compiler would have no reference for type substitution. So, nope, that particular declaration won't work.

Comment: I don't understand how it be possible to reuse the code of `AParser.parse()` in `BParser`.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - push the common code from `AParser` up into a base abstract class, and then extend ***both*** concrete parsers (`AParser` and `BParser`) from the abstract class.

Comment: Common code involves instantiating `P` and calling methods on it specific to `APacket`.